# Using an EntryElement with AutoComplete features and Google Places API

Tags: ios, google-places-api, monotouch.dialog

Im wondering if you can help me with a problem:

Problem: Im trying to create a dialog with an EntryElement that allows a user to enter an address. As the user enters the address I would like to call the Google Places API to bring back a list of results to ensure the address is valid. The results should be displayed as a list of StyledStringElements which the user can select.

Does anyone have any advise on how to best achieve this?

Thanks and regards. Adam!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer can be found here:
[Xamarin Forums](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/10823/using-an-entryelement-with-autocomplete-features-and-google-places-api#latest)